# asp.net webapi application_start event firing more than once (Visual studio + iisexpress)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API 2 project in visual studio 2015. No custom coding yet, just added the project. I put a break point on `Application_Start()` and hit F5 to debug. The debugger breaks at the break point as expected if I let it run then a browser window opens. So far so good.

Now hitting F5 (refresh) on the browser window the debugger breaks on the break point again. --> But Why??

Subsequent F5 (refresh) on the browser don't break at the application start event.

I need to do certain processing only on the first time when the application starts. My processing is currently not idempotent and will break if run multiple times (second time in this case)

Any ideas about this behavior? Is this specific to VS and IIS Express debugging?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out McAfee was the culprit. (Ugh..)

http://forums.asp.net/t/2047724.aspx?MVC+application+hosted+in+IIS+executes+Application_Start+twice+